# Given that at least $n$ elements from $A$ must be members in $C$, how many different sets C can be created by combining elements from $A$ and $B$?

Tags: combinatorics

**Generalized Problem:**

Let $A$ and $B$ be two sets where $|A|=a$ and $|B|=b$.

Let $C\subset A\wedge B, |C|=c$.

Given that at least $n$ elements from $A$ musts be members in $|C|$, how many distinct sets $C$ can be created by combining a total of $c$ elements from $A\wedge B$?

**Example:** A team of 23 football players and 3 trainers have been awarded 10 tickets to a concert. To increase their probability of receiving a ticket, the cunning trainers deceitfully tell the players that at least 1 trainer must attend the concert. In how many different ways can the tickets be distributed among the 26 team members?

When initially trying to solve this problem I penned the following: $${3\choose1} {25\choose9}=3\times2042975=6128925$$

I thought that ${3\choose1}$ gives the number of ways to choose one of the teachers; and that ${25\choose9}$ gives the number of ways to choose nine people from the remaining 23 players and 2 trainers. Then, I thought that the product of ${3\choose1} {25\choose9}$ would equal total number of ways to distribute the tickets due to the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product). (This method does not provide the correct answer.)

After attempting to solve the problem with the above method, I tried to solve it in a different way:

$$\text{"number of allowed ticket distributions" = "total number of ticket distributions"} - \text{"number of ticket distributions with no trainers"} = {26\choose10} - {23\choose10} = 4167669$$

This method yields the correct answer.

**My Questions:**

- Why does the first method fail? Where is the my reasoning flawed?
- What combinations arise when using the first method that do not when using the second method?

Comment: In your example, $\binom{3}{1}$ picks a "*first*" trainer to receive a ticket and this ticket and trainer will be considered special.  Then, in the $\binom{25}{9}$ it is possible that a second or even a third trainer is selected, but these trainers will not be considered special.  Changing who the "special" trainer was winds up being counted as a different outcome despite the actual ticket recipients not being different.  E.g. the outcome A-BCabcdefg is considered different than the outcome B-ACabcdefg when they shouldn't be.

Comment: To correct this, you can break into cases based on the number of trainers selected giving a final count of $\binom{3}{1}\binom{23}{9}+\binom{3}{2}\binom{23}{8}+\binom{3}{3}\binom{23}{7}$.  Note that by adding $\binom{3}{0}\binom{23}{10}$ we would get a total of $\binom{26}{10}$ as per [Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde's_identity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is multiple counting in the first method.

Let's call the trainers $A,B,C$ and the players $1,2,\dots23$.

Then possibility $A,B,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$ is counted if $A$ is the "chosen" trainer and $B$ is among the other $9$, but it is also counted if $B$ is the "chosen" trainer and $A$ is among the other $9$.